# How to combine 2 DataFrame columns with different shape and also with different columns name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can someone help me out to combine/Union 2 dataframe who has different shapes with different columns names.

As you can see 1 dataframe is with 3 columns and the 2nd dataframe contains only 1 column.

I want to put dataframe 02 clientid column below to dataframe 01 Turtlemint profile_id column and create new column with vertical name and mentioned value as Life against all the value we put under the 1st dataframe columns like I mentioned inside the image.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Does my reply answer your question? if so, could you mark it as so?

Comment: @Tobias Yes its working for me, but can you help little bite more .... I just add 1 step which required for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have change the second DF column name same as first DF and then outer joined them, so we can the first DF extra columns.

Code:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'clientid': "Turtlemint profile_id"})], join='outer', axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

above we haven't changed the second DF column name permeant so still I have use the column name *clientid*. Here the simple logic is if the ID exist in both table give value *Life* or else *None*.

ADD column:

```
df1['Vertical'] = np.where(df1['Turtlemint profile_id'].isin(df2['clientid']), 'LIFE', None)
```

Comment: Hello Rajan Thank you so much for providing me great solution, but can you also help me out to achieve 1 more step, as I mentioned inside my image. I want Vertical columns contain value against appended data.

Comment: Hello, @beginner_Coder do you how you getting the value Life. You just wanna give life to the id frrom df2 ?

Comment: yes I just want to put Life value. write now I am doing this by manually

Comment: Thy this code @beginner_Coder

Answer (score 0):

Using `append` while changing the column name of your second dataframe, you can achieve this.

A simple, but similar example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,2,3], ['A', 'B', 'C']]).T, columns=['nr', 'lt'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=['D', 'E', 'F'], columns=['lt2'])
df3 = df1.append(df2.rename(columns={'lt2':'lt'}))
df3.loc[df3['nr'].isnull(), 'Vertical'] = 'Life'
```

Dataframes:

```
df1:
  nr lt
0  1  A
1  2  B
2  3  C

df2:
    nr lt
0    1  A
1    2  B
2    3  C
0  NaN  D
1  NaN  E
2  NaN  F
```

Output:

```
    nr lt Vertical
0    1  A      NaN
1    2  B      NaN
2    3  C      NaN
0  NaN  D     Life
1  NaN  E     Life
2  NaN  F     Life
```

Comment: Yes its working for me, but can you help little bite more .... I just add 1 step which required for me.

Comment: @beginner_Coder see my edit